# WebRequest class, optimize code?

Tags: c#

I made a program that performs hundreds of hits per second at different websites.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create ("SecureControl / / reset / passwordreset");
request.Headers.Add ("Authorization", "Basic asdadsasdas8586"); 
request.ContentType = "application / x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Host = "www.xxxxxxxxxx.com";
request.method = "POST";
request.Proxy = null;
request.Headers.Add ("& command = requestnewpassword");
request.Headers.Add ("& application = netconnect");
```

This code is in a loop of thousands of repetitions so adding headers individual consumes too much memory by the CPU.

The idea is to use it as the winsock in vb6.
For example:
Winsock1.Sendata AllHTTPHeaders
Thus only sending data without adding headed by header.

I want to save cpu resources, my question is if there is any way not to declare the code adding unnecessary headers.
There is a way to store in one variable http headers ?.
and sending a faster way.

Something like: HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) ALLHEADERS.

Any ideas?
Thank You.

Comment: can you see what the string output of this header would be, and just build the string you need?

Comment: Jeremy I think you misunderstood me.
What I want to do is save in a single variable header and send it using WebRequest class.

For example:

Var optimize = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nUser-agent: example\r\nReferer: example\r\nCookie: example\r\n\r\n"
to use it in this way:

WebRequest.Create (Optimize)

This to save cpu resources instead of adding headers in each repetition of the loop.

Comment: _"The idea is to use it as the winsock in vb6"_ - so your question is _"How to use sockets to perform an HTTP request?"_, and that has been asked and answered before, see duplicate. Why are you executing this particular request, are you trying to write malware?

Comment: @CodeCaster
The request is just one example.
the main idea is to save resources not add headers in each loop.

Comment: Did you benchmark this code? Did you measure that the adding of the headers is the slowest or most resource-intensive part of it? Does sending an HTTP request by sockets (as in the proposed duplicate) do what you want?

Comment: I'm using the WebRequest class that accepts the automatic addressing and why not use sockets.

  as I mentioned earlier I just want to send the headers as would be done through a socket so fast without adding header by header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share this instance of [WebHeaderCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and assign it to the webrequests' header properties:

```
private static readonly WebHeaderCollection Headers = new WebHeaderCollection()
{
    {"Foo", "bar"}
};
```

You can also set [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to null once prior to making any requests, so you won't have to do that explicitly for every single request.

Consider:

```
private static readonly WebHeaderCollection Headers = new WebHeaderCollection()
    {
        {"Authorization", "Basic asdadsasdas8586"},
        {"command", "requestnewpassword"},
        {"application", "netconnect"}
    };

private static void Start(int nRequests)
{
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < nRequests; ++i) {
        SendRequest();
    }
}

private static bool SendRequest()
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("URL");
    request.Headers = Headers;
    //Set other properties (like .Method) here

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
        //Returns boolean indicating success
        return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}
```

Comment: such, thanks for responding.
Could you give me a simple example of how to implement it?

Comment: @SergioGarciaLopez I have added a short example to my post, to give you an idea of how you cuold implement it. You should probably change the headers I used for my example.

Comment: Really thank you very much !, implement the code right now!

Comment: I got an error saying:
This header must be modified With The right property.